# How do I do a SQL JOIN on 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and I am trying to get data out of three different tables but am not sure of the syntax that I should use.

I have a table called full_daily_data_1 with the following fields
Symbol
Trade_Date
Day_Open
Day_High

I also have a table called custom_indices_xref  with the following fields:
symbol
Custom_Index_Name

And a table called daily_index_weightings with the following fields:
Custom_Index_Name
Symbol
Trade_date
combo_weighting

Right now, I have this as a select statement to get the data I need out of two tables:

```
SELECT 
    Symbol, 
    Trade_Date, 
    Day_Open, 
    Day_High
FROM 
    full_daily_data_1 
WHERE 
    trade_date >= '2012/01/01' AND
    trade_date <= '2012/01/31' AND 
    symbol in (SELECT symbol from custom_indices_xref WHERE Custom_Index_Name = 'Agricultural-Chemical-and-Fertilizer-Stocks');
```

But what I want is the following data for each symbol for each date in the date range
symbol
Day_Open
Day_High,
Custom_Index_Name
Symbol
Trade_date
combo_weighting

So basically, needing to add combo_weighting from the daily_index_weightings table for the selected days and symbols.  What should my SQL statement look like to accomplish this?

I tried this, but I get a SQL syntax error, so not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
SELECT 
    full_daily_data_1.Symbol, 
    full_daily_data_1.Trade_Date,
    full_daily_data_1.Day_Open, 
    full_daily_data_1.Day_High,
    full_daily_data_1.Day_Low,
    daily_index_weightings.combo_weighting
FROM 
    full_daily_data_1
WHERE 
    trade_date >= '2012/01/01' AND  
    trade_date <= '2012/01/31' AND 
    Symbol in (SELECT symbol from custom_indices_xref WHERE Custom_Index_Name = 'Agricultural-Chemical-and-Fertilizer-Stocks')
JOIN 
    daily_index_weightings ON 
        daily_index_weightings.symbol = full_daily_data_1.Symbol AND 
        daily_index_weightings.Trade_Date = full_daily_data_1.Trade_Date ;
```

Comment: This may help you understand joins and types of joins http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Like you would SQL JOIN 2 tables ?

Comment: Note: In a `SELECT`/`JOIN`.  `JOIN` should come before `WHERE`.  (I often cut-paste myself into that mistake!)

Comment: So did anything work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT fdd.Symbol, fdd.Trade_Date, fdd.Day_Open, fdd.Day_High, fdd.Day_Low, diw.combo_weighting 
 FROM full_daily_data_1 fdd 
 INNER JOIN custom_indicies_xref cix ON fdd.symbol=cix.symbol 
 INNER JOIN daily_index_weighings diw ON fdd.symbol = diw.symbol
 WHERE 
 trade_date >= '2012/01/01' AND  
 trade_date <= '2012/01/31' AND 
 cix.Custom_Index_Name = 'Agricultural-Chemical-and-Fertilizer-Stocks'
```

The INNER JOINS could be changed to LEFT JOIN if required.

Alternatively, since your second and third tables also match the Custom_Index_Name fields (which is bad design, by the way):

```
 SELECT fdd.Symbol, fdd.Trade_Date, fdd.Day_Open, fdd.Day_High, fdd.Day_Low, diw.combo_weighting  
 FROM full_daily_data_1 fdd 
 INNER JOIN (custom_indicies_xref cix ON fdd.symbol=cix.symbol 
      INNER JOIN daily_index_weighings diw ON cix.Custom_Index_Name = diw.Custom_Index_Name)
 ON fdd.symbol = cix.symbol
 WHERE 
 trade_date >= '2012/01/01' AND  
 trade_date <= '2012/01/31' AND 
 cix.Custom_Index_Name = 'Agricultural-Chemical-and-Fertilizer-Stocks'
```

Comment: You should show where the `trade_date` WHERE clause fits into this.

Comment: Come to think of it...Why do you even need the second table at all???  Can a symbol have multiple Custom_Index_Name values?

Comment: You don't need both the JOIN and IN clause for `custom_indicies_xref`. Remove the IN clause and replace it with `AND Custom_Index_Name = 'Agricultural-Chemical-and-Fertilizer-Stocks'`

Comment: And also, why not use trade_date BETWEEN '2012/01/01' AND '2012/01/31'

Comment: That's just a style preference. Mysql IN is much slower than JOIN in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql clauses are out of order and you should use alias for your table names, just makes it easier to read. Another thing I noticed is your fields in your WHERE clause are ambiguous.

```
SELECT 
    FDD.Symbol, 
    FDD.Trade_Date,
    FDD.Day_Open, 
    FDD.Day_High,
    FDD.Day_Low,
    DIW.combo_weighting
FROM 
    full_daily_data_1 FDD
JOIN 
    daily_index_weightings DIW ON 
        DIW.symbol = FDD.Symbol AND 
        DIW.Trade_Date = FDD.Trade_Date ; 
WHERE 
    FDD.trade_date >= '2012/01/01' AND  
    FDD.trade_date <= '2012/01/31' AND 
    FDD.Symbol in 
    (SELECT symbol from custom_indices_xref WHERE Custom_Index_Name = 'Agricultural-Chemical-and-Fertilizer-Stocks')
```

Comment: I don't think it would be necessary to join on Trade_Date also.